# tile docking line gone in aps 16.04

Tags: 16.04, menu, docking

I updated form 15 to 16.04.  I have not been about to get the top line of my apps to show up when I dock.  The file, edit, etc.  is missing. I have put sudo sevrice lightdm restart.  It worked and gave me back my docking heading.  However when I restarted my computer it want back to not having them.   I restalled ubuntu-desktop and unity. But nothing.   If I go to raszor desktop it work fine.  any ideas on what to do?